# VBA to come up with all the combinations of two columns of data

Tags: excel, vba

I have two columns of data (column A, column B) and I want to list all the combinations of these in columns C and D. I.e. If column A has 5 numbers in a list and column B has 3 numbers in a list I should have 15 combinations listed in columns C and D. This is just an example the length of the data in columns A and B change dynamically.

I am pretty new to VBA, so a simple step by step guide would be appreciated.

[image: visual of question above]

Answer (score 1):

VBA is not required for this.

In **C1** enter:

```
=INDEX(A:A,ROUNDUP(ROW()/COUNT(B:B),0))
```

and copy down. In **D1** enter:

```
=INDEX(B:B,MOD(ROW()-1,COUNT(B:B))+1)
```

and copy down.

[image]

You can add or remove items from either list.  You can use numbers or text values in either list.

**EDIT#1**

To remove the unnecessary zeros at the bottom of columns **C** and **D**, In **C1** use:

```
 =IF(ROW()>COUNT(A:A)*COUNT(B:B),"",INDEX(A:A,ROUNDUP(ROW()/COUNT(B:B),0)))
```

before the copy-down and in **D1** use:

```
=IF(ROW()>COUNT(A:A)*COUNT(B:B),"",INDEX(B:B,MOD(ROW()-1,COUNT(B:B))+1))
```

This is based on knowing that there can be only ***Na*** X ***Nb*** combinations.

Comment: This works great!  Thank you.  Is there a way to exclude the 0's after it completes the combinations?

Comment: @Max  See my **EDIT#1**